# How to resolve EF Core context with Unity container in a .net 4.7 project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, unity-container, .net-4.7.2

I have an issue where I need to upgrade my projects to the latest version of .NET, currently all projects are .NET 4.7 or .NET Standard 2.0 using Entity Framework 6 this is then exposed through a WCF service which gets its instantiations via Unity.

The plan was to start with an upgrade from EF 6 to EF Core 3 and then also decouple it using Inversion of control to be able to change the underlying data access if needed, this has been started with all repository calls reference the interface IMyDbContext and seems to be okay.

Now i have an issue of how to resolve IMyDbContext from the Unity container in the WCF app given that it is .Net 4.7 and the project containing MyDbContext is .net core 3.

Any pointers/references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a solution with multiple projects, some on .Net Framework and some on .Net Core I use something like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        static MyContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        }

        [InjectionConstructor] //Used to specify the constructor to Unity
        public MyContext() 
            : base("Name=MyContext")
        {
        }

        public MyContext(string connectionString) //Used to resolve de dependency in .net Core
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }   
    }
```

Startup.cs in .Net Core MVC project

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddScoped<MyContext>(_ => new MyContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

And in the .Net Framework project is passed as a parameter to a repository, IDoStuffRepo, which is registered like this:

```
public override void Initialize(){
   this.Container.RegisterType<IDoStuffRepo, DoStuffRepo>(new DisposableTransientLifetimeManager());
}
```